# MongoDb query by Date if date stored like String

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

have a small trouble. Recently merge existed Db from SQL to MongoDb, and all date fields like (createdAt, updatedAt) in SQL and now in MongoDb was stored as String: `"Mon Aug 23 2016 09:55:04 GMT-0700 (PDT)"`so question is. Can I use MongoDb query methods like `$gte, $lt` to fetch particular data? or do I have any other approach to do that, without reconverting whole db, and change data fields to MongoDb date object?

Comment: I know you don't want to, but the right answer is to reconvert/fix these fields to use MongoDB date object. Otherwise you'll be fighting this messy representation forever.